# How do I make music interactive using Asterisk?

Tags: music, asterisk, freepbx

I recently started my own computer repair business & use FreePBX/Asterisk for my phone system. Just wondering if it's possible to make my music on hold interactive.

I would like to let callers change the music that they are listening to by pressing a button.

It's a small business so I would only have 1-2 callers on hold maximum, so processing power shouldn't be an issue.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for beginner do this feature.

Possible ideas how to do that

1) before moh i your dialplan setup features

2) on feature fire use external ami app to switch moh class for this channel, after that UNHOLD and do hold again.

Complexity is average if your dialplan is writed by you or much above average if you use freepbx or other GUI.

**ps** some softphones and/or providers will not send dtmf while holding.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-config-musiconholdconf/

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-config-featuresconf/